# URL alias, tokens is replacing 0s and 1s with node and entity

Tags: 7, path-aliases, tokens

Has anyone seen a case that url aliases or tokens end up replacing certain numbers in a url with the words node and entity. A UTC Timestamp in my url ended up replaced like this:

```
node4328522entityentity
```

I cannot find any errors in the watchdog table. It seems like it's trying to "encode" numbers, but those are numbers that shouldn't be encoded. Or another possiblitiy I've thought of is maybe it is trying to grab something out of a non-existent array at index 0 and 1?

Comment: For anyone else looking out there. After updating webforms and reimporting these nodes, it fixed the urls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems pretty similar to what is asked in the question about [Tokens causing incorrect text substitutions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157624/tokens-causing-incorrect-text-substitutions/158377#158377) .

Refer to my answer in that question for various options to further debug what might be going on. If you can, please enhance your question (by editing it) to indicate which of the possible reasons in your case do apply, or don't apply at all.

Also note the brand new comment there (from "[diego](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/41337/diego)"), 
here is what that comment says:

> I was able to find a work around at east for the Webform submissions. If I use a Rule to send the email (using [data:{field-name}-display] tokens) instead of the Webforms built in email function it doesn't seem to substitute any of the tokens.

Answer (score 3):

I have been having a similar problem as shown in the question Pierre links to. Unfortunately we haven't been able to find the source of the problem yet to find a fix, but I have found a work around that has been working for me temporarily.

What I have been doing is going into the database and running the following query:

```
UPDATE url_alias SET alias = REPLACE(alias, 'node', '1') WHERE pid <> 0;
```

This replaces all instances of the word 'node' with the number '1' in the 'alias' column of the 'url_alias' table. You can fairly easily edit it to be 'entity' and '0'.

Comment: I don't have access to the database directly, but I will see if the person who does can fix it this way.

Comment: I'm sure it goes without saying but make sure you do backups before running queries on your database!